# Why does magnetic dipole moment $\vec{\mu}=\gamma \vec{L} $?

Tags: angular-momentum, magnetic-moment

I have often seen that the relationship between magnetic dipole moment $\vec \mu$ and angular momentum $\vec{L}$ expressed as 
$$\vec{\mu}=\gamma \vec{L} $$

But consider a current loop of a charged particle in this diagram:[image]

The magnetic moment $\vec \mu$ and angular momentum $\vec{L}$ points in different directions. How then is $\vec{\mu}=\gamma \vec{L} $ still valid?

Comment: Wrong radius. It means angular momentum respect to the axis, not respect to a point. Because you can choose the origin anywhere you want, that's not giving information. In contrast, w.r.t the axis is an objective manner.

Comment: @FGSUZ what would be the correct expression for $\vec{L}$ then?

Comment: r is the radius from the axis to the particle. It is perpendicular to the axis.

Comment: you could define the origin to be at the particle and then $L=0$...if you were choosing arbitrary origins.